# Outlook add-in, how to tell if user is selecting new times in email from meeting request

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

If the user is using the preview pane. The NewInspector event does not fire.
What should I be hooking into?

if the user opens the message I get this event.

```
Application.Inspectors.NewInspector += InspectorOnNewInspector; 

From there i can hook to

var appointmentItem = ((Outlook.AppointmentItem) inspector.CurrentItem);
((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event) appointmentItem).PropertyChange += ThisAddIn_PropertyChange;
```

full code

public Outlook.Inspector CurrentInspector { get; set; }
        public string Organizer { get; set; }

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Inspectors.NewInspector += InspectorOnNewInspector;
        Application.ActiveExplorer().SelectionChange += MeetingDurationAddIn_SelectionChange;
    }

    private void MeetingDurationAddIn_SelectionChange()
    {
        try
        {
            var currentView = Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentView;

            if (currentView is Outlook.CalendarView)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
        catch
            (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    private void InspectorOnNewInspector(Outlook.Inspector inspector)
    {
        try
        {
            if (inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
            {
                CurrentInspector = inspector;
                var creationTime = ((Outlook.AppointmentItem)CurrentInspector.CurrentItem).CreationTime;
                if (creationTime == DateTime.Parse("1/1/4501 12:00:00 AM"))
                {
                    NewAppointment = true;
                }
                if (CurrentInspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
                {
                    Appointment = true;
                }
                if (CurrentInspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.MeetingItem)
                {
                    Appointment = false;
                }
                var appointmentItem = ((Outlook.AppointmentItem)CurrentInspector.CurrentItem);
                ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event) appointmentItem).Send += OnSend;
                ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event) appointmentItem).PropertyChange += ThisAddIn_PropertyChange;
                MeetingId = appointmentItem.GlobalAppointmentID;
                Organizer = appointmentItem.Organizer;

                EditDuration();
            }
        }
        catch
            (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The object firing the event (inspectors) must be stored in a global (class) variable to prevent it from being garbage collected. You set up the event handler on an implicit variable (Application.Inspectors) that will be released the next time GC runs.

Secondly, preview pane is not an inspector, so NewIsnpector event will nto fire. Use the Explorer.SelectionChanged event.

Comment: I added the code. Nice catch. but that does not get me to the preview item.

Comment: Updated the code.. can you help me with the  if (currentView is Outlook.CalendarView) line. It's not correct. i guess i shoudl be checking for something else.

Comment: Once again, the object firing the events (Explorer) must be in a global variable to prevent it from being garbage collected.